# Worklight Geofence Error Dynamically not updating the triggers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, geofencing

Implemented geofencing in worklight. The first time the geofence is triggered it works fine.  After the user leaves the area I try to update trigger and startAcquisition again but in this scenario time triggers are not getting triggered.

```
//display the position to the user
function displayPosition(pos) {
    $('#longitude').html('<b>Longitude:</b> ' + pos.coords.longitude);
    $('#latitude').html('<b>Latitude:</b> ' + pos.coords.latitude);
    $('#timestamp').html('<b>Timestamp:</b> ' + new Date(pos.timestamp));
}

function alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr(geoErr) {
    alert('Error acquiring geolocation (' + geoErr.code + '): ' + geoErr.message);
}
var triggers={};
    var geoPolicy = WL.Device.Geo.Profiles.LiveTracking();
    geoPolicy.timeout = 60000; // set timeout to 1 minute
    geoPolicy.maximumAge = 10000; // allow to use a position that is 10 seconds old


function getFirstPositionAndTrack() {
    alert('Click OK to proceed to acquire starting position');

    // use GPS to get the user's location

    // note: to see at high-accuracy, change RoughTracking above to LiveTracking

    // get the user's current position
    WL.Device.Geo.acquirePosition(
            function(pos) {

                displayPosition(pos);

                 triggers = generaTriggers(pos);

                startTrace({ Geo: geoPolicy },triggers,{ Geo: alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr })
            },
            function(geoErr) {
                alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr(geoErr);
                // try again:
                getFirstPositionAndTrack();
            },
            geoPolicy
        ); 
}

function onConnectSuccess(){
    // start up acquisition process
    getFirstPositionAndTrack();

}

function onConnectFailure(){


getFirstPositionAndTrack();

}

function wlCommonInit(){
    // Common initialization code goes here
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
        onFailure: onConnectFailure
    });

    // keep running while in background on Android; will show a notification
    WL.App.setKeepAliveInBackground(true);
}

function generaTriggers(pos){

    var triggers = {
          Geo: {
            posChange: { // display all movement
              type: "PositionChange",
              callback: function(deviceContext) {
                  displayPosition(deviceContext.Geo);
                }
            },

            leftArea: { // alert when we have left the area
              type: "Exit",
              circle: {
                longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                radius: 200
              },
              callback: function(deviceContext) {
                alert('Left the area');
                //resetTriggers(deviceContext.Geo);
                startTrace({ Geo: geoPolicy },resetTriggers(deviceContext.Geo),{ Geo: alertOnGeoAcquisitionErr });
                //WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'exit area'}, true);
              }
            },

            dwellArea: { // alert when we have stayed in the vicinity for 3 seconds
              type: "DwellInside",
              circle: {
                longitude: pos.coords.longitude,
                latitude: pos.coords.latitude,
                radius: 50
              },
              dwellingTime: 3000,
              callback: function() {
                alert('Still in the vicinity');
                //WL.Client.transmitEvent({ event: 'dwell inside area'}, true);
              }
            }
          } 
        };


    return triggers;
}

function resetTriggers(deviceContext){

//alert();
return generaTriggers(deviceContext);

}

function startTrace(policy, trigger, geoerr){
alert("trace");
                WL.Device.startAcquisition(policy, trigger, geoerr );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The state for each trigger is maintained between calls to startAcquisition; it is relying on the trigger name to identify a unique configuration and isn't checking whether the underlying configuration is different.

Generally speaking you have 2 options.

1. For the triggers you wish to update be sure to use a name that is different than the current set of triggers. Note that if there are existing triggers whose internal state should be maintained (for example, whether the device has already been in the configured area or not), you need to maintain the old name.
2. Make an additional intermediary call to startAcquisition passing in a triggers object with all the triggers you will want to update removed (thus, deleting them), and then the final call will work with the original names (as a new configuration will be applied).